# Reading NSData from a XML CData section instead of an NSString

Tags: objective-c, xml, dom, cdata

I will most likely end up answering my own question, because I need this bug fixed before I can go on, but then it is here for documentation purposes. NOTE: I am not using the SAX parser like every other question/answer I found.

```
NSMutableData* data = ...

NSXMLNode* nodeCDATA= [[NSXMLNode alloc] initWithKind:NSXMLTextKind options:NSXMLNodeIsCDATA];
[nodeCDATA setObjectValue:data];

NSAssert([nodeCDATA.objectValue isKindOfClass:[NSData class]], @"NSXMLNode setObjectValue didn't use a NSData");
```

It should be noted that within the same function, the NSAssert at the end DOES NOT FIRE.
However after sending the xml through to the server, I get a NSString as return type.

```
NSXMLNode* nodeCDATA= [dx childAtIndex:0];

id obj= nodeCDATA.objectValue;
if (![obj isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
    NSLog(@"Why am I getting a %@ returned from a CDATA section!?",[obj class]);
```

The output is ...

```
2012-01-05 13:58:29.336 auth[18773:1f03] Why am I getting a __NSCFString returned from a CDATA section!?
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

===== UPDATE =====

The question is still open. Best solution that I found was to find an external base64 encryption solution to encode the NSMutableData into a NSString and then use setStringValue. Then I use the decrypt of base64 to decrypt the string returned by stringValue, avoiding the problem.

To be exact, I used the - (NSString *)base64Encoding from http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour to jimmy rig it for now, but I will most likely implement raw writing of NSData bytes into BSON format and see if that will cut it. I read that base64 gives about a 33% increase in data size and I think I want to avoid that if possible.

Solutions to above are still very welcome.

=== MORE UPDATE ===

Some options I have looked into are DTD and XSL. The same issue was in MSXML.dll a long time ago. It would be just fine if I could assign a DTD or do an XSL translation to convince the Apple API that my data is base64 character data that I want returned as NSData. Does anyone have code for this? I did find the non-normative use of the xs:base64Binary tag in DTD, but I haven't tried if the Apple ID accepts it. Too much work just to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

CDATA sections are not intended to allow you to pass binary data. They're specifically intended to mark a section of content that must be interpreted only as **character data** rather than markup. There is no semantic difference between data inside a CDATA node and data inside a text node. If you need to encode binary data, you need to convert it to something UTF-8-compatible. Base64 is the typical choice.

Here's a relevant passage from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML):

> New authors of XML documents often misunderstand the purpose of a CDATA section, mistakenly believing that its purpose is to "protect" data from being treated as ordinary character data during processing. Some APIs for working with XML documents do offer options for independent access to CDATA sections, but such options exist above and beyond the normal requirements of XML processing systems, and still do not change the implicit meaning of the data. Character data is character data, regardless of whether it is expressed via a CDATA section or ordinary markup.

The end result of all this is that while the `NSXMLNode` APIs may accept an `NSData` as input, they're under no obligation to provide you with an `NSData` after parsing an external document. In fact, since the contents of a CDATA section are character data, it's more correct for `NSXMLNode` to return an `NSString` (which, as you said, it's doing).

Comment: Kevin, you are entirely correct. But, what I am looking for is a way to get that NSData in any case. I have looked at DTD and XSL with perhaps using the xs:base64Binary tag, but I don't see a clear cut way of getting this done.

Comment: As I have also stated, when I pull out the data from the node in the same function (the NSAssert statement), the data is returned as a NSData. So, I want to achieve the same thing after transmission.

Comment: @PLG: When you set the `objectValue` to an `NSData` and then immediately pull it out again, it's going to give you the exact same `NSData` you gave it. But if you parse an XML document and then ask the node for its `objectValue` you'll get an `NSString`. I would recommend using `stringValue` and `setStringValue:` instead, and using your own transformation between `NSData`<->`NSString` (e.g. with base64 or some such)

Comment: Thanks for your responses Kevin. The only thing that I find strange is ... why would Apple include a feature where you can pass an NSData to an XML Document, whereby it will automatically be stored for you (with some reading you figure out it is base64) without a way to read that format in some way through the API. There has to be something missing here.

Comment: @PLG: What alternative would they do? Crash?

Comment: If they are going to automagically transform my NSData object to a base64 encoded object, then I want a way to automagically change it back. That simple. As I mentioned before I already figured out a workaround myself, but I would like a solution to the problem, which is telling the XML Dom the data type so that I can get the NSData type back.